# Make form buttons disappear after clicking them (game)

Tags: javascript

I had a developer work on this game for me (so I'm not really a coder - just a rookie!), but I'd like to add a quick mod myself.....

Is there a simple way to make each form button disappear once selected, then all buttons reload/display again once a new round loads up?

http://www.slinkyproductions.co.uk/games/movie-hangman/

Many thanks.

- Scott

Comment: This question is a tad too broad since it lacks details on the implementation. "Yes there are ways to hide buttons once they're clicked on, and quickly show them on a random other event." But somehow I doubt that's the question you're intending asking.

Answer (score 0):

Change buttons to

```
<input name="letterZ" onClick="Letter('Z')" type="button" value="Z" class="letter" id="btnZ">
```

And add this line to Letter() function

```
$("btn"+param).hide();
```